# Extract string between optional brackets

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract strings between multiple brackets, but it should also work without any brackets. This is what I've got now

```
Pattern pw = Pattern.compile("\\(?(.*)\\)?\\^\\(?(.*)\\)?");
    Matcher m = pw.matcher("2+1^(3+4)");
    if(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }"
```

This prints:

```
2+1
3+4)
```

Whereas it should be:

```
2+1
3+4
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try making it non-greedy by using:

```
.*?
```

instead of `.*`

Your regex:

```
Pattern pw = Pattern.compile("\\(?(.*?)\\)?\\^\\(?(.*?)\\)?");
```